# Strange logs while using different send methods in ibm-mq

Tags: java, logging, ibm-mq

I`m using `JmsSenderService#sendRequestAndWaitResponse(String request, MQMDHeaders mqmdHeaders, MQRF2Headers mqrfh2Headers`) to get response "synchronously".

Also I have `BaseSenderMessageListener`, which is logically not related to the first method (is related to `JmsSenderService#send(Object var1, MQMDHeaders var2, MQRFH2Headers var3)`.

Both methods put messages to the same queue, but responses are read from different queues.

The problem is: I get some strange logs, although everything is working fine. And I want to get rid of this logs. I have logging in `BaseSenderMessageListener` and it doesn`t work, so the problem is before listener gets to work.

Logs example:

```
Could not initialize log file, java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: mqjms.log.0.lck
August 5, 2022 at 10:01:21 AM GMT[boundedElastic-5] com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsProviderExceptionListener
An exception has been delivered to the connection's exception listener: '
                       Message : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ1107: A problem with this connection has occurred.
An error has occurred with the IBM MQ JMS connection.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.
                         Class : class com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:595)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:217)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:156)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1858)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:228)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1461)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:674)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1051)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:667)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:209)
                               : org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolMessageConsumer.receive(JmsPoolMessageConsumer.java:79)
                               : org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doReceive(JmsTemplate.java:788)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doReceive(JmsTemplate.java:765)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$receiveSelected$9(JmsTemplate.java:749)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:747)
                               : ru.vtb.uip.jms.jmsmessaging.service.JmsSenderServiceImpl.readWithSelector(JmsSenderServiceImpl.java:194)
                               : ru.vtb.uip.jms.jmsmessaging.service.JmsSenderServiceImpl.lambda$null$5(JmsSenderServiceImpl.java:244)
                               : reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:56)
                               : reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
                               : reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:126)
                               : reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
                               : reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
                               : io.opentracing.contrib.concurrent.TracedCallable.call(TracedCallable.java:32)
                               : java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                               : java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
                               : java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                               : java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                               : java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
     Caused by [1] --> Message : com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2195' ('MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR').
                         Class : class com.ibm.mq.MQException
                         Stack : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:217)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:156)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1858)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:228)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1461)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:674)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1051)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:667)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:209)
                               : org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolMessageConsumer.receive(JmsPoolMessageConsumer.java:79)
                               : org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doReceive(JmsTemplate.java:788)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doReceive(JmsTemplate.java:765)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$receiveSelected$9(JmsTemplate.java:749)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
                               : org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:747)
                               : ru.vtb.uip.jms.jmsmessaging.service.JmsSenderServiceImpl.readWithSelector(JmsSenderServiceImpl.java:194)
                               : ru.vtb.uip.jms.jmsmessaging.service.JmsSenderServiceImpl.lambda$null$5(JmsSenderServiceImpl.java:244)
                               : reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:56)
                               : reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4046)
                               : reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:126)
                               : reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
                               : reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
                               : io.opentracing.contrib.concurrent.TracedCallable.call(TracedCallable.java:32)
                               : java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                               : java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
                               : java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                               : java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                               : java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
'.

EXPLANATION:
null

ACTION:
Review the exception details for further information.
```

Comment: What version of IBM MQ are the jar files from?  `reason '2195' ('MQRC_UNEXPECTED_ERROR')` is a very generic error that I have not seen returned in recent versions.

Comment: i`m using mq-jms-spring-boot-starter-2.4.3

Comment: What version of IBM MQ jars are in use?

Comment: @JoshMc sorry, new to topic, misundersood. jar version 9.2.1

Comment: I world suggest you run a IBM MQ JMS trace and see what happens directly before the 2195, this usually will show you the true cause.